# How to append element to variable to be render in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Given a react component like below (https://jsfiddle.net/69z2wepo/28684/):

```
var Hello = React.createClass({
  render: function() {
    let { cond, name } = this.props;
    let content, content2;
    if (cond){
      content = (<div>Hello { name } </div>);
      content2 = (<div>content 2</div>);
    }

    return (
      <div>
        { content }
        { content2 }
      </div>
    )
  }
});

ReactDOM.render(
  <Hello name="World" cond={ true } />,
  document.getElementById('container')
);
```

How can I achieve something like:

```
content += (<div>content 2</div>) //not working
```

and then render the content in a single content variable instead of both content and content 2?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

```
var Hello = React.createClass({
  render: function() {
    let { cond, name } = this.props;
    let content, content2, contents;
    if (cond){
        content = (<div>Hello { name } </div>);
      content2 = (<div>content 2</div>);
      contents = [content, content2];
    }

    return (
        <div>
        { contents }
      </div>
    )
  }
});

ReactDOM.render(
  <Hello name="World" cond={ true } />,
  document.getElementById('container')
);
```

https://jsfiddle.net/69z2wepo/28687/

Comment: the answer works but react will display Warning: Each child in an array or iterator should have a unique "key" prop. In order to make it work without warning, we have to add key to each item in array [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/w38450q0/)

Comment: Each element in an array needs key={} attribute so react can track each new element in the virtual dom